# Is OpenZeppelin Defender a centralized solution to make gas-free transactions

Tags: gas, openzeppelin, decentralization, gasless

The point is to make gas-free transaction solution for a specific set of smart contracts without creation of private blockchain in Ethereum.

Would it be considered as centralized thus adding point of failure and breaking the whole essence of decentralised applications? If that is so, how to implement it without creation of private blockchain?